# Programatically generate a form based on a JSON-LD context

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I want to create a html form for generating new JSON-LD documents based on a given context. For example let's assume I want to create person based on the type Person (https://schema.org/Person).

What is the best way to get all fields with all its data types?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: My best guess would be to use a JSON LD processor with the `expanded` serialization option to get the context for each field. However, this does not reveal the datatype of each field, only the context url such as http://schema.org/telephone . So I have to resolve the context recursively until I get datatypes such as `number` or `boolean`... I cannot imagine that I am the first person that wants to do this but I cannot find any resources on this.